# Weird behaviour with Sinatra "before" block checking http headers

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm making an API with Sinatra, the application it's working fine, but I've found and error and I don't know how to solve it.

I'm making a GET request from my frontend, sending a token via HTTP Headers, I want to protect a route and I'm doing it with a before block.

Here is my code:

```
before do

    content_type :json
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    token = request.env['HTTP_MY_TOKEN']
    p "TOKEN: 1" 
    p token

    protected_routes = ["/link/all", "link/create"]
    if(protected_routes.include?(request.path_info))
        p "TOKEN: 2" 
        p token
        if !token
            p "TOKEN: 3" 
            p token
            halt 401, { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }, { error: 'Error, No token provided' }.to_json
        end
    end


end
```

The output is:

```
"TOKEN: 1"
nil
"TOKEN: 2"
nil
"TOKEN: 3"
nil
```

But If I comment the "halt" line, the output is:

```
"TOKEN: 1"
"eyJhbG12cidaasOiJaqIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1Njg0...."
"TOKEN: 2"
"eyJhbG12cidaasOiJaqIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1Njg0...."
```

What is the problem with my code ?

Thanks!

Comment: I just tested the code that you showed and it works just as expected (with or without the halt (which of course shouldn't matter since we supply a token and don't get there)). So please add some more info about what you are doing if you what help solving this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think the problem is with my CORs configuration... I'm digging into it

Comment: I recommend putting a breakpoint in there to invesigate what's going on